# Pruning a tree recursively depending on keys (python)

Tags: python, recursion, tree

New to python and trying to determine how to prune a decision tree recursively by creating a new tree. If a node has a key in the "keys_to_prune" list, it and its descendents are not included in the new tree. Here is what I came up with:

```
def prune_tree(tree, keys_to_prune)
    new_tree = Tree()
    for child in tree.children:
        if child.key not in keys_to_prune:
            new_tree.children.append(child)
        else:
            prune_tree(child, keys_to_prune)
    return new_tree
```

The tree object (Tree()) has .key, .value, and .children attributes. This code does not seem to work-- it appears to be checking empty nodes with no key and no value. Any assistance would be helpful!

Comment: What is the value of the .children attribute if the node has no children?

Comment: It's an empty list []

Answer (score 0):

A dict is a kind of tree. Consider this example:

```
{
    "a": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        {
            "c": 3,
            "d": 4,
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "a": {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 2,
        },
        "z": 99,
    },
}
```

If `keys_to_prune` contains only `a`, the desired pruned-tree would look like this:

```
{
    "b": {
        "z": 99,
    },
}
```

In other words, if you see a key that should be pruned, **do nothing**: don't
add it to the new tree, and don't explore its subtrees. Otherwise, add the
child to the new tree *and* explore the child for deeper pruning.

But the more subtle problem is that your recursive implementation is mixing two
different strategies. On the one hand, it is assembling and returning a new
tree. On the other hand, it is ignoring the return value and expecting
recursive calls to deeper levels to mutate child levels in place. You need to
choose one approach or the other. For example, if you stick with the idea of
returning new trees, you might take an approach like this:

```
def prune_tree(tree, keys_to_prune)
    new_tree = Tree()
    for child in tree.children:
        if child.key not in keys_to_prune:
            new_child = prune_tree(child, keys_to_prune)
            new_tree.children.append(new_child)
    return new_tree
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter stuff out using a list comprehension:

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, k, v, children=None):
        self.key = k
        self.value = v
        if children:
            self.children = children
        else:
            self.children = []
    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.key, self.value, self.children))

def pruned(t, keys):
    return Tree(t.key, t.value, [pruned(c, keys) for c in t.children if c.key not in keys])

import random

def random_tree(max_depth=5, max_children=3):
    nb_children = random.randrange(max_children+1) if max_depth > 0 else 0
    return Tree(random.randrange(100), random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), [random_tree(max_depth-1, max_children) for _ in range(nb_children)])

t = random_tree()
s = pruned(t, set(range(0, 100, 2))) # keep only odd keys

print(t)
# (9, 'd', [(93, 'n', [(17, 'j', [(23, 'h', [(65, 'o', [(80, 'u', []), (89, 'b', [])]), (97, 'e', [(64, 'l', []), (81, 'q', []), (51, 'o', [])])]), (63, 'y', [(65, 'c', [(27, 'h', []), (25, 'z', []), (30, 'k', [])]), (78, 'r', [])]), (65, 'z', [(15, 's', [(39, 'm', []), (69, 'a', [])])])])]), (63, 'a', [(67, 'r', [(18, 'j', [(97, 'i', [(88, 'n', [])]), (6, 'a', [(72, 'l', []), (81, 'n', [])])])]), (52, 'q', [(92, 'z', [(27, 'm', [(88, 'm', []), (39, 't', [])]), (28, 'u', [(40, 'c', [])])]), (1, 'z', [])]), (99, 'r', [(49, 'x', []), (46, 'h', [(38, 'm', [(72, 'v', [])]), (98, 'h', [(75, 'z', []), (67, 'q', [])]), (78, 'w', [(67, 'v', []), (78, 'p', [])])]), (5, 'a', [(1, 'y', []), (73, 'g', [(87, 'o', []), (63, 'i', [])]), (67, 'z', [])])])])])

print(s)
# (9, 'd', [(93, 'n', [(17, 'j', [(23, 'h', [(65, 'o', [(89, 'b', [])]), (97, 'e', [(81, 'q', []), (51, 'o', [])])]), (63, 'y', [(65, 'c', [(27, 'h', []), (25, 'z', [])])]), (65, 'z', [(15, 's', [(39, 'm', []), (69, 'a', [])])])])]), (63, 'a', [(67, 'r', []), (99, 'r', [(49, 'x', []), (5, 'a', [(1, 'y', []), (73, 'g', [(87, 'o', []), (63, 'i', [])]), (67, 'z', [])])])])])
```

I must say I'm a bit puzzled by the use of `key` and `value` in your trees. Perhaps we could remove class `Tree` completely and use a `dict` directly?

```py
def pruned(t, keys):
    return {k:pruned(v, keys) for k,v in t.items() if k not in keys}

import random

def random_tree(max_depth=5, max_children=3):
    nb_children = random.randrange(max_children+1) if max_depth > 0 else 0
    return {random.randrange(100): random_tree(max_depth-1, max_children) for _ in range(nb_children)}

t = random_tree()
s = pruned(t, set(range(0,100,2)))

print(t)
# {63: {37: {}}, 73: {4: {57: {74: {15: {}, 58: {}}, 4: {}}, 58: {4: {33: {}, 56: {}, 70: {}}, 49: {}, 38: {85: {}}}, 66: {22: {79: {}}, 1: {}, 2: {9: {}, 19: {}}}}}}

print(s)
# {63: {37: {}}, 73: {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I would create a new "pruned" tree using recursion.

To keep things simple, I will create a binary tree. I am going to use this image as a reference.[image]

Here is the code for **creating the tree** from the example image so we have something to work with.

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left  = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

####All of the main Nodes####
tree_start = Tree("Has feathers")
can_fly = Tree("Can fly")
has_finns = Tree("Has finns")
hawk = Tree("Hawk")
penguin = Tree("Penguin")
dolphin = Tree("Dolphin")
bear = Tree("Bear")

#####Connect the nodes####
#does it have feathers?
tree_start.left  = can_fly
tree_start.right = has_finns

#can it fly?
can_fly.left  = hawk
can_fly.right = penguin

#does it have finns?
has_finns.left  = dolphin
has_finns.right = bear
```

**Here is how we can create a newly pruned tree using recursion**

```
#Recursive Funciton
def prune_tree(treeNode, keys_to_prune):
    
    if treeNode is None:
        return 

    if treeNode.data in keys_to_prune:
        print("pruning this branch: {}".format(treeNode.data))
        return 

    newTreeNode = Tree(treeNode.data) 

    if treeNode.left is not None:
        newTreeNode.left = (prune_tree(treeNode.left, keys_to_prune))

    if treeNode.right is not None:
        newTreeNode.right = (prune_tree(treeNode.right, keys_to_prune))

    return newTreeNode
```

**Call our pruning function**

```
prunedTree = prune_tree(tree_start, ["Can fly"])
```

This last part is optional, but we can use similar recursion logic to print out the branches of our new tree

```
def print_tree(tree):
    if tree:
        print(tree.data)
        print_tree(tree.left)
        print_tree(tree.right)
```

call the print function

```
print_tree(prunedTree)
```

final output of everything is:

```
pruning this branch: Can fly
Has feathers
Has finns
Dolphin
Bear
```